# How do I reduce the height of the area where commands are entered?

Tags: normal-mode

I seem to have messed with some settings which have resulted in the area where I enter commands now being 2 characters in height. See the screenshot below:

[image: vim-command-entry-form]

What do I have to set in my init.vim file (I am using Neovim) to return this area to being 1 character in height?

Comment: @filbranden that seems to have done the trick. I had recently installed the `coc.nvim` plugin and lifted the configuration for it from the repo and it seems one of the things that this changes is `cmdheight`. If you want to write your comment up up as an answer I'd be glad to accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that this is caused by the [`'cmdheight'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27cmdheight%27) option, which configures the number of screen lines to use for the command-line.

You can reset it to its default of 1 with:

```
:set cmdheight&
```

Since the default is to keep just one row for the command-line, it's possible you got this configured in your vimrc, so just removing it from there should solve the issue for you.